# Elfinder: Dev works, but 'identical' Live won't enter content blob into MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, elfinder

I'm new to elFinder, and have it working perfectly on my dev environment using the Mysql driver (after fixing some small sql errors). The live environment is set up identically as far as I can see (apache, php, mysql), except for the dev being on a windows box and live being shared hosting.

On the live environment, the file upload works except that the row inserted into the DB has a null longblob in the content column. On the dev environment it inserts the file into the DB column. I don't think it is an elFinder issue - I'm guessing rather something to do with how the tmp file is stored during the insert, but I'm hoping someone will have a suggestion of where to look or more clarity on that particular process.

I have set the PHP max file upload settings and the LimitRequestBody in the .httaccess file.   Also checked the MySQL max_allowed_packet size.  They're all ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated the issue:  The MySQL driver of elFinder relies on the LOAD_FILE() function of MySQL to insert the data into the DB.  My shared hosting provider does not give me permission to use that function.   I decided to use the simpler LocalFileSystem driver, and it works perfectly on the live server, but I can't get it working on my dev machine... go figure!  Will have to trace that problem another day.